# Delphi. How to get a pointer to a dynamically created object

Tags: pointers, delphi, components

I would like to access components via pointers instead of searching using FindComponent. The following assignment works for components placed on the Form, but not for dynamically created components. For example:

```
var
  Pbtn: ^TButton;
  Button2: TButton;

begin
  Pbtn := @Button1;
  Showmessage(pbtn.caption); // works well

  Button2 := TButton.Create(Form2);
  Pbtn := @Button2;
  Showmessage(pbtn.caption); // not work

...
```

Comment: An object variable, like Button2, IS a pointer!

Comment: "_not work_" is wrong: it works as intended. What happens to you and what did you expect instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A class type is a reference type, so object instances of a class type are already represented as pointers. Don't use `^`/`@` to refer to these objects (that will only refer to the pointers themselves, which is rarely ever needed in most situations), eg:

```
var
  Pbtn: TButton;
  Button2: TButton;
begin
  Pbtn := Button1;
  ShowMessage(pbtn.Caption); // works well

  Button2 := TButton.Create(Form2);
  Pbtn := Button2;
  ShowMessage(pbtn.Caption); // also works well
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works just fine.

But why the second message in your example doesn't return any text then? That is because when you dynamically create a TButton no value is assigned to its caption and therefore your second message returns an empty string.

If you change your code to assign a specific caption to your second Button you will see that it works just fine

```
  Pbtn := @Button1;
  Showmessage(pbtn.caption); // works well

  Button2 := TButton.Create(Form3);
  //Assign some value to the dynamically created button's caption
  Button2.Caption := 'It works!';
  Pbtn := @Button2;
  Showmessage(pbtn.caption); // not work
```

But why there is a caption on design-time placed button. That is because Delphi IDE sets the caption to be same as the component name that was placed on the form. This is done just out of convenience to the Delphi user.

Comment: This is all true, but of course the *real* solution to the OP's problem is to realise that an object variable *is* a pointer, so there is no need for `^TButton`, `@`'s and `^`'s when you work with object variables. In fact, it is not only unnecessary, it is also dangerous. For instance, you mustn't take the address of a local variable and use this after the `end` of the associated function.